# Lookup values within nested sql command

Tags: mysql, sql, nested

We have a need where we want to map certain values based upon specific conditions in different columns and then further need to do a lookup in different table to fetch values
e.g. 
Table 1

```
plant    country   v1      v2      v3      v4      v5      score
ny01       us      123     456     678    abc    def       good
ln01       uk      456     678     abc    def    def       better
ny03       us      def     1233    xxx    999    909       better
ln02       uk      788     4561    ab678  abc    def       good
```

Table 2

```
lookupcodes       globalhqno 
123                 usxx
456                 US001
abc                 UK001
1233                US022
abc678              UK033
```

so definition of Headquarters is
when country = us then it is v1
when country = uk then it is v3

and definition of globalhqno. is 
lookup values for headquarters1 into table 2 and find values

final output

```
plant    country   headquarters1      globalhqno 
ny01       us        456                 US001
ln01       uk        abc                 UK001
ny03       us        1233                US022
ln02       uk        4561                UK033
```

I started with case statement and i am able to get headquarters1 working however i am trying to find how to write possibly nested sql or another alternative to get values of headquarters1 from case statement output and lookup values in table 2 to populate globalhqno.

Comment: I do not see the relationship between your desired results and your sample data.

Comment: You seem to be using v2 for ny03.......us

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to derive a column based on your rules, and then use that in your join.

```
select
*
from
(
Select
*,
case when country = 'US' then v1 -- or v2, your example isn't clear
when country = 'UK' then V3
end as join_column
from 
<table1>) t1
inner join <table2> t2
  on t1.join_column = t2.lookupcodes
```

Comment: Thank you Andrew the above syntax got it working for me.